# Why is my domain value cookie equal to 0 at the developer tools chrome?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cookies

it supposed to be value 1 or other than zero and that makes it unable to insert data into my database cart when i click a product. My ajax statement was working successfully if i click the product but it does not insert anything data into the database table cart.

this is my init.php

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect ('127.0.0.1','root','','tutorial');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo 'Database connection failed with following error: '. mysqli_connect_error();
die();
}
session_start();
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tutorial/config.php';
require_once BASEURL. 'helpers/helpers.php';

$cart_id = '';
if(isset($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE])){
$cart_id = sanitize($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE]);
}

if(isset($_SESSION['SBUser'])){
$user_id = $_SESSION['SBUser'];
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'");
$user_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$fn = explode(' ', $user_data['full_name']);
$user_data['first'] = $fn[0];
$user_data['last'] = $fn[1];
}

if(isset($_SESSION['success_flash'])){
echo '<div class="bg-success"><p class="text-success text- center">'.$_SESSION['success_flash'].'</p></div>';
unset($_SESSION['success_flash']);
}

if(isset($_SESSION['error_flash'])){
echo '<div class="bg-danger"><p class="text-danger text-center">'.$_SESSION['error_flash'].'</p></div>';
unset($_SESSION['error_flash']);
}
```

this is config.php

```
<?php 
define('BASEURL', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tutorial/');
define('CART_COOKIE','SBwi72UCklwiqzz2');
define('CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE',time() + (86400 *30));
```

this is add_cart.php

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tutorial/core/init.php';
$product_id = sanitize($_POST['product_id']);
$size = sanitize($_POST['size']);
$available = sanitize($_POST['available']);
$quantity = sanitize($_POST['quantity']);
$item = array();
$item[] = array(
'id'       => $product_id,
'size'     => $size,
'quantity' => $quantity,
);

$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost')?'.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:false;
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '{$product_id}'");
$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = $product['title']. 'was added to your cart.';

//check to see if the cart cookie exist
if($cart_id != ''){
$cartQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
$cart = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
$previous_items = json_decode($cart['items'],true);
$item = 0;
$new_items = array();
foreach($previous_items as $pitem){
    if($item[0]['id'] == $pitem['id'] && $item[0]['size'] == $pitem['size'])    {
        $pitem['quantity'] = $pitem['quantity'] + $item[0]['quantity'];
        if($pitem['quantity'] > $available){
            $pitem['quantity'] = $available;
        }
        $item_match = 1;
    }
    $new_items[] = $pitem;
}
if($item_match != 1){
    $new_items = array_merge($item,$previous_items);
    }
$items_json = json_encode($new_items);
$cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 days"));
$db->query("UPDATE cart SET items = '{$items_json}', expire_date = '{$cart_expire}' WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
setcookie(CART_COOKIE,'',1,"/",$domain,false);
setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false);
}else{
//add the cart to the database and set cookie
$items_json = json_encode($item);
$cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 days"));
$db->query("INSERT INTO cart (items,expire_date) VALUES ('{$items_json}','{$cart_expire}')");
$cart_id = $db->insert_id;
setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false);
}
?>
```

if i change this part on file add_cart.php

```
$domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost')?'.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:false;
```

into `$domain = false;`

it still give me the value cookie = 0 when i inspect it in the developer tools chrome. can anyone had idea how to fix this so that im able to insert product details into my cart database.